A converging sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ for which $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty} \gamma_{n}a_n \neq 0}$

A a positive  sequence $\{\gamma_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is called a test-sequence if for every positive sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ we have that :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \quad \text{converges} \iff \lim_{n\to \infty} \gamma_na_n =0$$
Explain that if $\{\gamma_n\}$ is unbounded then there exists a subsequence $\{\gamma_{n_{k}}\}$ s.t $\gamma_{n_{k}} \ge k^2$ and build with the help of this subsequence a converging sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ for which $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty} \gamma_{n}a_n \neq 0}$ and conclude that there doesn't exist a test-sequence.

Since $\{\gamma_n\}$ is unbounded :
$$\forall M>0 , \exists n\ge1  , |\gamma_n|\ge M$$
therefor for $k=1$ we pick $n_1$ s.t $|\gamma_{n_1}| \ge 1 ^2$ 
for $k=2$ we pick $n_2 > n_1$ s.t $|\gamma_{n_2}| \ge 2 ^2$ 
we continue by induction and we get that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we choose $n_k>n_{k-1}$ s.t  $|\gamma_{n_k}| \ge k^2$ since  $\gamma_n$ is a positive sequence then $\gamma_{n_k} \ge k^2 $ 
but I am stuck at the second part of the question I thought  that since $$\gamma_{n_k} \ge k^2   \implies 
 \frac{1}{\gamma_{n_k}} \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$
and the sum $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$  converges,then $\sum \frac{1}{\gamma_{n_k}}$ converges but I am failing to prove that  $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\gamma_n}{ \gamma_{n_k}} \neq 0}$.

Let $a_n=0$ if $n$ is not of the type $n_k$ and $a_{n_k}=\frac 1 {|\gamma _{n_k}|}$ for $k=1,2...$ Then $|a_{n_k}\gamma_{n_k}|=1$ for all $k$  and $\sum a_n$ converges.
If you insist that $a_n$ is strictly positive for all $n$, you can take $a_n=\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ when $n$ is not of the type $n_k$.

Do you mean :
$$a_n =
\begin{cases}
0 , n \neq n_k \
\frac{1}{|\gamma_{n_k}|}, n=n_k , k\in \mathbb{N}
\end{cases}
$$

You have the answer here.  The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|\gamma_{n_k}|} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty$.  However, $a_{n_k} \gamma_{n_k} = \pm 1$ which does not converge to zero.  According to the statement of the problem, $\gamma_n > 0$, so absolute value is not needed.
